# Fast Infix Searching

Tags: .net, autocomplete, solr, full-text-search, sphinx

I'm building an autocomplete that will have to query a 10+ million words/phrases quickly, and am running into some problems.  My first idea was to go through some sort of trie/ternary tree structure, but those are strictly prefix matching, which isn't good enough for my application (i want full infix matching).  I then moved to some of the bigger solutions,  SqlServer FullText Indexing, Lucene, Solr, Sphinx, but Lucene and SqlServer FullText Indexing aren't actually fulltext, but prefix with nifty features (soundex, proximity, etc).  I tried to think of a way Levenshtein edit distance could help, but couldn't find a way to be both at least reasonably accurate as well as supporting words with high edit distances (i.e. google and ogl.  edit distance of 3, but 3 is way to high a threshold a general case).

My question is, how do powerhouses like Google/bing etc do it?  Do they just brute force it after a bit?  I would imagine no, but I can't find any support of that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess an N-gram approach may help. Then there is http://sna-projects.com/cleo/ which does what you require.

Comment: "Lucene isn't fulltext"? Can you elaborate on that? It seems you have a definition different from the one most people use. Also, what have you tried with each of Solr/Lucene/Sphinx/etc? Are you aware that Solr has a specific component to deal with autocomplete?

Comment: I take fulltext to mean that if i search "*talli*", "metallica" is matched.  under both sqlserver and lucene that is not the case.

Comment: @hermitt : Lucene/Solr searches for *terms*, which can be words or parts of words or anything you want depending on config. See ngrams as suggested by aitchnyu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable `queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);` in Lucene, you can use leading and trailing wildcards like:

```
*talli*
```

That would pick up all single-word terms that contain "talli" including "Metallica".

This may not be fast enough for you, but in some cases (prefix-only wildcard searches to be precise) if you can preprocess the query string you might be able to get by with the old "reverse the term and index that also" trick:

```
acillateM
```

Answer (score 1):

Lucene/Solr can do this very easily. The unit of search in Lucene/Solr is a [Term](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/Term.html), which is usually a word but can be really almost anything depending on how [text analysis](http://futupark.wordpress.com/2008/04/01/text-analysis-inside-lucene/) is configured.

With Solr there are many ways to implement this (ngrams/shingles, facet prefix, TermsComponent, ...). Recent versions of Solr come with a specific component for [autocomplete based on spell checking](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester).

Answer (score 0):

When I needed infix search in 2013, I made some research. The only way I found was [Sphinx engine](http://sphinxsearch.com/). One needs to configure it to support infix search

```
index tra
{
  [...]
  enable_star=1
  min_infix_len=2
}
```

After this it deals with the problem in eye-blink. I think it was about 200K records to search. I used a local engine to imitate in-memory search library.